# How to enable billing permission for IAM in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-billing, aws-permissions

I have already assign billing permission and full administrator permission to IAM role but still I IAM user getting permission issue. How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

First give billing permission to the IAM user then move to My Account -->
IAM User and Role Access to Billing Information  --> Edit --> enable Activate IAM access.

[image]

Now your IAM user able to see billing permission.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two pre-requisites for an IAM user/role to view the Billing console.

1. The user/role should have necessary IAM permissions.
2. 'IAM User and Role Access to Billing' must be activated. This has to be done by logging in as the root user and is disabled by default.

A video and article about the same is [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-billing-access/).